# How do you evaluate/test accuracy of Text-to-Speech (TTS) models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, speech-recognition

As the title implies... 
For instance, for Machine Translation, we have BLEU.
For categorization, we have categorical crossentropy, for binary categorization, we have binary crossentropy, etc. etc.

For machine learning methods, I'm not sure what we can use to measure accuracy of TTS models.

Comment: Is it feasible to 'translate' speech' output back to text (using a method of known accuracy) and then do matching of back-translated text with original text?

Comment: Hmph that's an interesting point... but still cascading errors can be unpredictable so I was looking for something more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to start exploring such a complex topic like TTS with a textbook. The [book by Paul Taylor](https://books.google.de/books?id=2UPljwEACAAJ) is good, it covers speech evaluation too

There are basically two approaches - subjective evaluation and objective evaluation. For subjective evaluation the most popular evaluation metric is MOS (mean opinion score test), but there are other more complicated tests like [MUSHRA](https://github.com/audiolabs/webMUSHRA)

For objective evaluations the most popular test is simple MCD test (mel cepstral distortion), but there are more advanced ones. For more details see

[Speech synthesis evaluation Sébastien Le Maguer](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335948444_Speech_Synthesis_Evaluation_-_State-of-the-Art_Assessment_and_Suggestion_for_a_Novel_Research_Program)

There are also more advanced machine learning methods for synthesis quality, see this paper:

[Towards Signal-Based Instrumental Quality Diagnosis for Text-to-Speech Systems by Tiago H. Falk, Student Member, IEEE, and Sebastian Möller](http://musaelab.ca/pdfs/J7.pdf)

also

[Non-intrusive Quality Assessment of Synthesized Speech using Spectral Features and Support Vector Regression by Meet H. Soni, Hemant A. Patil](https://www.isca-speech.org/archive/SSW_2016/pdfs/ssw9_PS2-1_Soni.pdf)